# Binding XAML TextBlock.Text with class TextBlock.Text

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

#### Question

How do I assign the value from the class section to the XAML section?

#### Class

```
 safeGasPrice.Text = root.result.SafeGasPrice.ToString();
```

#### XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="Here should be the text of the class" ></TextBlock>
```

Comment: What is `safeGasPrice` and how can you access it from the ViewModel (if you use MVVM)?

Comment: Hi, I have solved the problem. It's possible. The Question is closed.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the nature of StackOverflow. This is not a Help forum, but a Q&A collection. So if you think the way you solved the problem is useful for others, then post it as answer here. If on the other hand you realized your problem was due to some misunderstanding hardly relevant to others, you could also delete the question.